# Determine USB device file Path

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, libusb

How can i get USB device file path correctly in Linux.
I used command: find / -iname "usb" and got the result as below:

```
/dev/bus/usb
/sys/bus/usb
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb
/sys/kernel/debug/usb
```

Under /dev/bus/usb i see:

```
001  002  003  004  005  006
```

But I think they aren't files as i need.

Under /sys/bus/usb/devices/:

```
sh-3.2# ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/
1-0:1.0  1-1:1.0  3-0:1.0  5-0:1.0  usb1     usb3     usb5
1-1      2-0:1.0  4-0:1.0  6-0:1.0  usb2     usb4     usb6
```

And Under  /sys/bus/scsi/devices/ when i pluged an USB i see:

```
2:0:0:0      host0        host2        target2:0:0
```

And when i removed USB i see:

```
sh-3.2# ls
host0
```

So which device file is used for USB? How can i indentify it? I need to make a C program with USB device file...

Further more, could you explain to me the number 1-1:1.0? What does it mean?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need the device file for?

Comment: I need to check informations which related to USB device. 
So i think i will send ioctl to USB device file and read the feedback data? Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of information?

Comment: Read/write verification to USB device, and get USB device's information such as: speed, name, ...

Comment: What do you mean with "read/write verification"? Is this for some specific device? Or are you trying to duplicate `lsusb`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> So which device file is used for USB? How can i indentify it?

What you see behind `/sys/` is mainly configuration/information about devices. `/dev/bus/usb` is what you are looking for. I think that the following article can help you

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7466?page=0,0

Is quite old, but still it can help you. (In the article they speak about `/proc/bus/usb`, today we have `/dev/bus/usb`)

> Further more, could you explain to me the number 1-1:1.0? What does it mean?

The generic form is

```
X-Y.Z:A.B
```

Each field identify the connection point of your device. The first two field are mandatory:

- X is the USB bus of your motherboard where is connected the USB system.
- Y is the port in use on the bus system

So the USB device identified with the string `3-3` is the device connected on the port 3 of the bus 3.

If you connect an USB hub, you are extending the connection capability of a single USB port. The Linux kernel identify this situation by appending the Z field.

- Z is the port is use on an hub

So, the USB device identified with the string `1-2.5` is the device connected on the port 5 of the hub connected on the port 2 of the bus 1.

USB specification allow you to connect in cascade more then one USB hub, so the Linux kernel continue to append the port in use on the different hubs. So, the USB device identified with the string `1-2.1.1` is the device connected on the port 1 of the hub connected on the port 1 of the hub connected to the port 2 of the bus 1.

A fast way to retrieve these information is to read the kernel messages (if you can).

```
$ dmesg | grep usb
[... snip ...]
[ 2.047950] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[ 2.202628] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c318
[ 2.202638] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2.202643] usb 4-1: Product: Logitech Illuminated Keyboard
[ 2.202648] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[... snip ...]
```

Then, the last two fields of the pattern (after colon) identify an internal section of an USB device :

- A is the configuration number of the device
- B is the interface number of a configuration

So, the string `4-1:1.1` means: the interface 1, on configuration 1 that is connected on the port 1 of the bus 4.

You can retrieve these information with the command `lsusb`.

Comment: This is very helpful to me.
But i still don't know which file can i send USB ioctl to it to get some informations...

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at libusb. It will abstract most of the work for you.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, `/dev/bus/usb` is the directory where you have to look. Which file *exactly*? It depends on where you connected the USB device. It's explained in the article and in the answer. Then as Alexandre said and suggested by the article, use `libusb`

Comment: Are these ports unique over multiple hubs?

Comment: This Oct 15, 2015 at 7:49 answer may be outdated? I navigate to /dev/bus/usb/001 and see device 004 as per Terminal$ lsusb: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18ec:5555 Arkmicro Technologies Inc. USB2.0 PC CAMERA
However in VLC -> Capture Device path: /dev/bus/usb/001, Play shows error Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/bus/usb/001'. Check the log for details.

Comment: [guessing] I do not know your device. Could it be that you need to provide `/dev/bus/usb/001/004` instead? Could it be that you need to provide `/dev/videoXXX` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question that has been answered a long time ago, but I keep stumbling upon it when looking for the command below. It might not be what OP asked for, but its possible that I'm not the only one who gets directed to this page when looking for this:

```bash
ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/
```

I'm a Linux noob and could not find any other command that gives me a list of serial devices with both device names and paths (e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`). For expample `dmesg | grep usb` does not give me the path that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/2*` and `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2*/manufacturer` and progressively add numbers to the `2*` part.. like `2-3:*`, `2-3:2.*` until you can match the name from `lsusb`, or use `idProduct` or `idVendor` instead of `manufacturer`.