# Embedded Linux USB CDC COM port name change question

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded, petalinux

I have Zedboard and I'm using USB CDC with petalinux 2017.4 version.

I successed communication with Windows serial communication program.

but, COM port name is 'ELMO GMAS'. It is default.

I want to modify it to customized name. what should i do

[image]

Comment: Is that part of the USB string descriptors?  (Use USBView to show them)

Comment: This article [Determine USB device file Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33140787/9014308) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Everybody. good day~