# How is the last digit in a USB Device Path Assigned/

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, usbserial

I am trying to have a Raspberry Pi Zero emulate a Cisco USB console interface (non-FTDI version). At a high level this is actually not that difficult:

- The `g_serial` driver running on the Pi can accept Cisco idvendor and idproduct parameters, so it will look roughly the same on a lsusb output
- The Linux host uses the same driver, `cdc_acm`, to connect to the Pi and the Cisco Device

The one problem I am having is that the kernel device path is slightly different between the two.

- Cisco: `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4.2:1.0`
- Raspberry Pi: `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4.2:2.0`

The Cisco's device path ends in `:1.0` and the Raspberry Pi's ends in `:2.0`. I know `1-1.4.2` comes from the USB hubs I am using on the host, but I do not know how the numbers after the `:` are assigned.
So my questions are:

- how is the last number assigned in the devpath? does it come from the host or attached device?
- is there anything I can do to the `g_serial` driver to make it better emulate the Cisco device and appear as `:1.0`

**Note**: I am not trying to fix this with a udev rule. My goal is to completely emulate the Cisco device with the Pi.

Comment: Why do you need that exact path? What the problem it will solve?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142810/5264491), the `:A.B` part is the USB configuration number (A) and the USB interface number (B). The numbers are probably fixed in hardware.